# Why is it acceptable to omit the generic type parameter here?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In the following snippet:

```
public class IDMapBase<T> extends HashMap<DeviceID, T> {
    public Map<DeviceID, T> filterMap(Set<DeviceID> neededIDs) {
        return entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> neededIDs.contains(e.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
    }
}
```

Why is it OK to simply say `Entry::getXX` instead of `Entry<DeviceID, T>>::getXX`?
I thought that `(Map.)Entry` would default to `Entry<Object, Object>`, which is not usable as an entry of a `Map<DeviceID, T>`.

Comment: Because your input `Map` has concrete type `<K,V>` that's why your entries also have type `Map.Entry<K,V>`

Comment: Type parameters for the owner component of method references can often be inferred by the compiler for you, but you are free to put them in explicitly as well.

Comment: The compiler infers these things for you.  That's its job.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think the OP was confused in that we treat `Entry` as a raw type when used standalone, in a member signature, or in a constructor invocation, but that we are willing to infer type arguments when used as the owner of a method reference.  Arguably we should do something similar for ctor invocations (dropping even the diamonds) when we can prove it's safe to do so.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: indeed, I never understood why the inference, which works for method invocations, couldn’t work for constructors as well. Especially as wrapping an object construction in a generic factory method, effectively adding no new information, allows omitting the type parameters even in Java 5…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input parameter has a enough type information for the compiler to infer all the intermediate generic types.

It can figure that "what comes in" and "what comes out" ... and the "steps in between" match up.

Example: the first call is **entrySet()**; so probably the surrounding class is a Map with defined K, V. So the compiler knows that it is dealing with some `EntrySet<K,V>` ... probably matching up with the generic type found on `neededIDs`.

And so on ... if you are interested in "inferring" the types yourself; I would suggest that you start by decomposing those fluently chained method invocations. One by one; figure what they return, and what you can know about the result types of each operation.